# Different brackets style on Scala function definition parameter list

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

What is the difference of the following two function definitions in Scala:

1) `def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = { <code removed> }`

2) `def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = { <code removed> }`

?

SBT's console REPL gives different value for them so looks if they are somehow different:

`sum: (f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int)Int`

`sum: (f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int)Int`

Answer (score 4):

The first definition is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curried), so that you can provide `a` and `b` at another time.

For instance, if you know the function you want to use in the current method, but don't yet know the arguments, you can use it so:

```
def mySum(v: Int): Int = v + 1
val newsum = sum(mySum) _
```

At this point, `newsum` is a function that takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int`.

In the context of summing it doesn't seem to make much sense; however, there have been plenty of times I've wanted to return different algorithms for parts of a program based upon something I know now, but don't know (or have access to) the parameters yet.

Currying buys you that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Scala functions support multiple parameter lists to aid in currying. From your first example, you can view the first `sum` function as one that takes two integers and returns another function (i.e. *curries*) which can then take an `Int => Int` function as an argument.

This syntax is also used to create functions that look and behave as new syntax. For example, `def withResource(r: Resource)(block: => Unit)` can be called:

```
withResource(res) { 
    ..
    ..
}
```