# Play! Framework templates parameter groups

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I've been reading the documentation on the Play! website and can't see where it explains what parameter groups are and what they would be used for.

What is the difference between:

```
@(title: String)(user: User)
```

And:

```
@(title: String, user: User)
```

If someone could help me out here it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look on this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684185/why-does-scala-provide-both-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters-pe

Answer (score 2):

As @mgosk suggests in the comments, multiple parameter lists are a standard feature of Scala functions and Google can answer that much better than I could.

With regard to *specifically Play templates* however, they're exceedingly useful.

**TLDR** Parameter groups in Play templates are useful for:

- passing implicit parameters to templates (from actions, and parent templates)
- providing a nice way to wrap content via Scala block invocation syntax

---

One reason you might use them is form passing implicit parameters to views. Implicit parameters are added to the call site by the compiler, and as the [spec points out](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#implicit-parameters) they must be marked as such in the last (or only) argument list, e.g:

```
@(title: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<h1>@title</h1>

The path is for this request is <b>@request.path</b>.
```

When calling that template from an action you don't have to explicitly provide the request header as long as there's one in scope ([see here for more details on that](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActions#Building-an-Action)).

Another really useful use for multiple parameter lists in templates is for "wrapping" content, especially given that Scala functions can be invoked with [braces instead of parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037194/285374). Say you have some partial templates which represent, say, several different widgets, but those templates are always surrounded by the same boilerplate HTML. You can then create a template wrapper (called `widgetWrapper.scala.html`) like this:

```
@(name: String)(details: Html)

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-name">@name</div>
  <div class="item-body">
    @details
  </div>
</div>
```

This can be invoked like so:

```
@(item: WidgetA)

@widgetWrapper(item.name) {
  <ul class="item-details">
    <li>@item.detail1</li>
    <li>@item.detail2</li>
  </ul>
}
```

This last technique is how one defines standardized "page chrome" or a site, e.g (file `standardLayout.scala.html`):

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(sidebar: Html)

<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>@title</h1>
    </header>
    <article>@content</article>
    <aside>@sidebar</aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

used like so:

```
@()

@standardLayout("My Page on Goats") {
  <p>
    Lots of text about goats...
  </p>
} {
   <ul class="sidebar-links">
     <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat">More about goats!</li>
   </ul>
}
```

As you can see, the content in the two brace-delimited sections are passed as [Twirl `Html`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.twirl.api.Html) to the layout template as, respectively, the main content and the sidebar (with the title passed in the first argument as a string.)

Such handiness is made possible by multiple parameter groups.